# Use SSL with Dropwizard datasource

Tags: mysql, ssl, dropwizard

I have a MySQL database that requires SSL to access (Google Cloud SQL but that should not affect anything). I can access it using a terminal command like this:

```
mysql -uroot -h $CLOUD_SQL_HOST \
    --ssl-ca=$CLOUD_SQL_KEY_LOCATION/server-ca.pem \
    --ssl-cert=$CLOUD_SQL_KEY_LOCATION/client-cert.pem \
    --ssl-key=$CLOUD_SQL_KEY_LOCATION/client-key.pem
```

How do I configure the Dropwizard datasource with the corresponding information? Very grateful for any pointers.

Comment: I believe this is not a dropwizard issue. You should look at DataSourceFactory, it constructs your datasource. All it does it use the jdbc driver for mysql to connect to your database. So what you need is to find out what the properties are that you need to set ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html ) and then supply them in your yaml configuration as properties to the datasource. It should then pick them up and it should hopefully just work

Comment: Thx for the answer and advice. However, I do think this is Dropwizard related since I need to figure out how to make it work alongside using the trust store for the incoming SSL connections. But I will continue investigating and update here if I find anything. I can always fall back to other means of authenticating the the access but SSL for inflight data would be a good thing even within Google itself.

Comment: Hm, the only key-store that I can see within DW is the one used by jetty. (See HttpsConnectorFactory). However I am not sure how that is handled internally. I figured it's a mysql issue because I imagine that they already implemented this and it is a matter of configuring the datasource correctly.

Comment: You might be right. I have tried to solve it for a while but decided to solve the authentication in another way for now. I'll update here again if I return to it.